# Building python2.7 bindings for openCV 3.1

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.1

I am trying to build opencv 3.1 from source, so that I can use it with python while specifying the "opencv_contrib" package during the build process, which allows me to use SIFT and SURF functionalities.

I can't get make to generate the python bindings I need for python to be able to use the opencv wrap module.

This is my cmake log (I am using ccmake for options):

```
lake@LAKE:~/opencv-3.1.0/build$ sudo cmake ../
sudo: unable to resolve host LAKE
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.2.3")
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "1.2.8")
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/lake/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7")
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found suitable exact version "2.7.6")
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4")
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "3.4.3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN)
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing:  HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Could NOT find PROTOBUF (missing:  PROTOBUF_LIBRARY PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Build libprotobuf from sources:
--     libprotobuf not found into system
--     The protocol buffer compiler not found
-- Tesseract:   NO
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.4.0+ x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz cvv hdf matlab sfm
--
--   GUI:
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     GThread :                    NO
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/lake/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
--
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/lake/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
--
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--     packages path:               /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 (ver 3.4.3)
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
--
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/lake/opencv-3.1.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/lake/opencv-3.1.0/build
```

The source correctly compiles and installs, but there are no .py files in the build folder what-so-ever.

What am I missing?

Comment: try only `sudo make` not `sudo cmake`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Why do you need .py files in the build folder? You have the path here: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Don't you? Then you just have to "import cv2"

Comment: since no .py files gets actually installed (copied) because none exists, python does not find any cv2 when I try to import it... happens only when I build from source....